# html height:auto is not working

Tags: asp.net, html, height

i want to make the height of the aspx page auto. So i have fixed main div height:auto. But it is not working.

Code:

```
   <div id='Div1' style="background-color: #F5F5F4; width: 100%; height:auto; padding: 15px;">
```

only top portion of the div is showing the background color.

Comment: add overflow:hidden, this should work for you If in your div is placed within an other

Comment: Height and Width are `auto` by default. Do you want to make the div 100% height?

Comment: i want to the div to grow if its content increase

Comment: Well, you've set exact dimensions, so it's not going to budge.

Comment: Best to be clear, `height: auto` *is* working - it's just no necessarily working *how you expect*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it has to be `overflow: auto` in the style attribute, which will render a scrollbar if the content is more than the pre-defined height

Answer (score 2):

You have `height: 550px` specified on your div, so it will always be 550 pixels high no matter how much content it has. If you would like its height to depend on its content instead, remove this declaration.